# How does the bear mother ensure her cubs don't escape during hibernation?

Tags: mammals

I have some questions relating to bears- more specifically, the brown bears we have in Scandinavia.

When they go into hibernation, do they fall asleep as we know falling asleep? If a bear mother brings her cubs into the den, how can she keep track of them? How can she make sure they don't wake up, leave the den and get lost in the snow?

Comment: Are you aware that brown bear cubs are born during hibernation? Or are you thinking about subsequent years when they remain with their mother?

Comment: Yes Bryan Krause - I'm thinking of the next year, when they go to sleep in the den together.

Answer (score 1):

She probably can't, but a bear that wanders out of the den away from it's mother probably won't be doing much reproduction.  Infant wanderlust will be strongly selected against.

Comment: Can you afd sources to back up your answer? It looks like a comment.